# Localize Preferences title

Tags: android, localization

I have an activity

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new GamePreferenceFragment());
transaction.commit();
```

containing `PreferenceFragment` subclass:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.game_prefs);
    preferenceScreenHelper = new PreferenceHelper(getPreferenceScreen());
```

The problem is that its action bar contains text "Preferences" and I have not found a way how to translate the title to another languages.

Comment: If your "Preferences" string is defined in a string resource, translation is trivial.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: This is what I complain - I have not defined displayed string :-(

Answer (score 1):

first of all define title for your actionbar(replace it with toolbar [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/) is a small example) in string.xml like that.

```
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">yourappName</string>
  <string name="actionbar_title">youractionbar title</string>
 </resources>
```

then access the toolbar set the title from string.xml after that define all of your resources in deffrent languages mean add different string.xml files in a localize folders just look at the documentation
[here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)
below small example is work for me hope it will be a good solution for you also.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
toolbar.setTitle(R.string.actionbar_title);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: toolbar.setTitle() - thanks, good catch. I will try it in the evening

Comment: if my answer help you so please accept the answer thanks :)

Comment: Sorry this is generic answer but I need specific answer for PreferencesFragment. I will google for its toolbar id meanwhile.